# How can I make my gas pedal and brake pedal more aligned?

Tags: dodge, grand-caravan, pedals

In my 2010 Dodge Grand Caravan, my gas pedal is low to the floor and the brake pedal is much higher up.  I have to lift my foot considerably to reach the brake.  It works fine to drive, but it is just a bother.

I do not have automatic pedal adjusters.  All Google searches bring up this auto adjusting feature, which I don't have.

I'll have to do this manually.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a drive by wire pedal assembly. You'd have to fabricate a new bracket that's higher up to mount this assembly to. It's probably beyond DIY type stuff. Just leave it. Next time you buy a vehicle, make sure to test drive it and make sure it's comfortable before you purchase it.

Comment: Can you pull the gas pedal any higher up with your foot? Is the pedal mounted to the floor or above your foot?

Comment: If there's no possibility of adjusting the pedals, and it really bothers you, you can try to bend the pedal, or cutting it and welding it so that it's aligned. Not very professional, but more of a last resort.

Comment: Can I suggest that whatever "fix" you do, do it on the *gas* pedal.  If your fix breaks, wouldn't you rather it be the gas pedal that breaks while doing 80 on the highway?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

[image]

http://www.creativecontrolsinc.com/products/pedalmates.htm

Or

In this video https://youtu.be/r0wANj7HWOY the guy screws a door stop to his gas pedal.